# Spring Data JPA does not persist objects in running mode but it does in debug mode

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My application operates in a weird way. In fact when debugging I can clearly see that my objects get persisted on the DB but when in running mode, JPA does not seem to persist them. The following is a code snippet from my source code :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a", schema="myschema")
public class A implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "id can not be null")
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

    @JsonIgnore
    // @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "a_b", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "a_id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "b_id") }
  )
  private List<b> blist = new ArrayList<>();

  //omitted source code
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "b", schema="myschema")
public class B implements Serializable{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  @NotNull(message = "id can not be null")
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "blist")
  @JsonIgnore
  private List<A> alist = new ArrayList<>();

  //omitted source code
}

 @Service
 public class MyService{
   //omitted source code
   public Optional<A> createCopy(A source, int bId) {
     B b = bRepository.findById(bId);
     A copy_ = this.copy(source);
     A target = aRepository.save(copy_);
     b.getAlist().add(target);
     bRepository.save(b);
     return Optional.of(target);
   }
     
   private A copy(A source){
     A target = new A();
     //copy one to one from source to target
     target.setB(source.getB());
     return target;
   }
 }
```

When debugging I can see that after making a call to `MyService#createCopy()` method, a new record is persisted in the DB within the table `a_b`. However when I simply run the server and then proceeds with a call to `MyService#createCopy()`, no additional record in `a_b` gets persisted.

Anyone ever encountered such an odd behavior before? And if yes how can one solve it please?

Comment: We have little to none information about your setup and code. This is kinda impossible to answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem as following (Thanks to @Ajit hint):

```
private A copy(A source){
     A target = new A();
     //copy one to one from source to target
     //instead of target.setB(source.getB()); I did this
     List<B> targetBlist = target.getBlist();
     source.getBlist().forEach(bObj -> {
        Optional<B> optB = bRepository.findById(bObj.getId());
        if(optB.isPresent())
          targetBlist.add(optB.get());
     });
     return target;
   }
```

Now that my problem is fixed I still cannot figure out what was the actual issue. It smells like this has to do something with lazy loading. In fact the only case where the problem does not occur is when I do inspect the `source#bList` before proceeding to the `copy()`. If anyone could clarify this to me I will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you have not set your new list again to b objet in your service, That's why you are not able to get records in within the table a_b. Change your service as below.

```
@Service
 public class MyService{
   //omitted source code
   public Optional<A> createCopy(A source, int bId) {
     B b = bRepository.findById(bId);
     A copy_ = this.copy(source);
     A target = aRepository.save(copy_);
    List<A> alist= b.getAlist();// Here b.getAlist() will return a independent list and adding any item within this list will not affect the list inside the object b.
     alist.add(target);
     b.setAlist(alist);// setting the new list to object b.
     bRepository.save(b);
     return Optional.of(target);
   }
```

Try it once and let me know if it works.

Comment: I have tried it but still. No new record is being persisted.

Comment: I have added my own answer please have a look at it.